# Soap Request keeps sending wrong value

Tags: c#, soap

I have created a small soap application which calls a service. The application reads a script file, splits the params, and replaces placeholders in a soap request body template.

(abbreviated for length)

```
<soap:Envelope...>
  ...
  <param1>?</param>
  ...
</soap:Envelope...>
```

The script would look like

```
myAction|50|...
```

and the tool takes care of replacing ? with 50 in the correct spot.

My problem comes when I want to send nothing for a param.

```
MyAction||....
```

I am just doing a string.Split(), the resulting array says the [1] == string.Empty

Replacing is like so (endtag is defined outside the loop so it progresses though the body)

```
 var endtag = body.IndexOf("</" + param + ">", endtag)
 var beg = body.Substring(0, endtag - 1);
 body = beg + param + body.Substring(endtag);
```

Looking at the resulting body, everything looks fine:

```
<soap:Envelope...>
  ...
  <param1></param>
  ...
</soap:Envelope...>
```

However, when my service receives it the string param1 has "\n     "

I can't figure out why this replacement is occurring.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options to handle lack of a SOAP parameter.

1. either don't write the `<param1>` element at all
2. or add a nil attribute to the element.

   <param1 xsi:nil="true" />

this is the most reliable way to ensure null values are passed to the service.

a SOAP parameter value of

```
<param1></param>
```

actually could refer to an empty string (not a null value)

Comment: My expectation was that an empty string be sent using <param></param> not necessarily a null. Or perhaps I did intend to send null with the expectation that WCF would translate that into the string.empty by default. I did solve my issue before i saw your post, I added code which would change any of the fore-mentioned in to there immediate close view -> <param />